# Repositioning element on the form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

I'm building that To-Do list app and I'm trying to create a "Add New task" button.

I wanted to create a new Task (TextBox) on the button click and also move the button bellow the TextBox added. So, I tried to create multiple panels and when the button was clicked, move the "New Task" button to the second panel and add the new textbox created to the first panel. And after that if the user wanted to remove that Task (TextBox), to repositionate the button and Tasks according to that.

Can someone please help me with that??

`

```
 private void btnNewTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Creating new Textbox
            TextBox txtTask = new TextBox();

            btnNewTask.Location = new Point(panel2);


            // txtTask parameter
            txtTask.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            txtTask.ReadOnly = false;
            txtTask.PlaceholderText = "Input a new Task.";
            txtTask.Location = new Point(panel1);

            //Adding txtTask.
            this.Controls.Add(txtTask);
        }
```

`

Comment: can you explain what is wrong with your current code?  It looks like you need to remove `btnNewTask` from `panel1.Controls` and add it to `panel2.Controls`

Comment: What are you expecting/want to happen each time you press the button?

Comment: @frankM_DN Yes that's what I want to do, but it throws me an error.

Comment: @duerzd696 on button click, I want to create a new TextBox (txtTask) and move the 'btnNewTask' bellows it.

Comment: ok well if you want anyone to help you, you should probably share what that error is and on what line it occurring at.

Comment: just use table layout panel, insert row. This will rearrange your form beautifully

Comment: @frankM_DN The problem is that my question has nothing to see with my code. I'm just asking if anyone can help me because I don't really know how can I add the new task and move bellows it the *btnNewTask* every time the button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

I founded The Solution. I deleted the panels and leaved the **btnNewTask** on the form.

On button click I needed to create and set the **txtTask** location as the **btnNewTask** location and change the Y location of **btnNewTask** to move it bellow. After that check if there was any other control that had the same or less Y location than **txtTask**, and if there was any, add 35 to his Y location too.

There is my new Code:

int c = 0;

```
    private void btnNewTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Creating new Textbox
        TextBox txtTask = new TextBox();

        // txtTask parameter

        Font font = new Font("Segoe UI", 10.0f);

        txtTask.Name = "txtTask" + ++c;
        txtTask.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
        txtTask.ReadOnly = false;
        txtTask.PlaceholderText = "Input a new Task.";
        txtTask.Size = new Size(817, 31);
        txtTask.Font = font;
        txtTask.Location = new Point(btnNewTask.Location.X , btnNewTask.Location.Y); // txtTask will get the "btnNewTask" Location

        btnNewTask.Location = new Point(txtTask.Location.X , btnNewTask.Location.Y + 35); // That should add 35 to the Y location  


        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            if (item.Location.Y >= txtTask.Location.Y)
            { // if there is an item that has greater Y location
                item.Location = new Point(item.Location.X, txtTask.Location.Y + 35); // It should increase its value as 35 too.
            }
            this.Controls.Add(txtTask);

        }
```

There's an example:

[image]

Thank for the help and ideas!